# How to mount .img file as read-only ext4, but give users read permissions to the whole fs?

Tags: linux, permissions, filesystems, mount

I have a `system.img` android's image file that has ext4 filesystem in it.
I mount it as

```
sudo mount -o ro system.img /mnt
```

I have two questions:

1. Why do I need root access to mount the image file?

Mounting the image file as user gives me the following error:

```
mount: /mnt: mount failed: Permission denied.
```

The user has full access to the `system.img` as it is the owner of file:

```
ls -l system.img
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user users 4877225984 Apr 12 19:13 system.img
```

The user doesn't have permission to mount the image file even if the user is the owner of the the directory to which I try to mount the image, like that:

```
$ mkdir system_mount
$ mount -o ro system.img system_mount
mount: system_mount: mount failed: Permission denied.
$ ls -l
drwxr-xr-x 2 user users       4096 Apr 12 19:38  system_mount
```

So why mounting always requires root access?

2. When mounted, the user still may not have access to some directories/files in the mounted filesystem if in the filesystem itself the permissions are not given to the user.

Access to some directories is not permitted, like `init.container.rc` file (`others` have no permissions):

```
-rwxr-x---  1 root 2000  3583 Dec 31  2008 init.container.rc
```

Trying to get contents of that file fails:

```
$ cat /mnt/init.container.rc
cat: /mnt/init.container.rc: Permission denied
```

I still can access that directory as root. And I could access it as user if I used `chmod -R 755` if the system was mounted as writable. But as it's not, I get the following kind of errors when I use chmod command:

```
chmod: changing permissions of '/mnt/d/tracing': Read-only file system
```

I want to give the user temporary read permissions to the whole filesystem WITHOUT modifying the `system.img` file (having it mounted as read-only), without actually changing the permissions in the filesystem.

How can I do that?

Comment: [`fuse2fs`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/fuse2fs.1.html)

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, yeah, that is exactly what I wanted. Thank you!

Comment: In the title there is "users" (plural). You may want to check this: [How to mount FUSE so that all users will have access to it?](https://superuser.com/q/1758100/432690)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mount FUSE (e.g. unionfs) so that all users will have access to it?](https://superuser.com/questions/1758100/how-to-mount-fuse-e-g-unionfs-so-that-all-users-will-have-access-to-it)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32008/how-to-mount-an-image-file-without-root-permission

Answer (score -1):

Kamil Maciorowski's solution, to use `fuse2fs`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: A one liner will probably get deleted. Please edit your post and show us how you used it. And you are allowed to tick your own answer

Comment: I'm not the one who voted down, but I agree that sole "use `fuse2fs`" makes a low quality answer. This is why I posted the hint as a comment (I had no time for proper answer at the time). We want answers to be educative. Your answer is there and it can be improved ([edit]ed), so I'm not going to post a competing answer. Possible improvements: what `fuse2fs` is; link to documentation; what FUSE is; security considerations; how to mount; how to unmount. See [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1557062/432690) which is more than "use `curlftpfs`"; this is what I mean.