# How to instruct the linux kernel to resolve all symbolic links in a mounted directory relatively to another root?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, symbolic-link

I have mounted an ISO at `/mnt`. The ISO is android's `system.img`. At the root it has a folder `etc` that is linked to `/system/etc`:

```
lrw-r--r--  1 root root    11 Dec 31  2008 etc -> /system/etc
```

But it seems that my linux system does not identify that this symbolic link actually points to a directory INSIDE `/mnt`, but not to my system root directory.

In the `/system/etc/` folder there's a standard `hosts` file:

```
$ cat /mnt/system/etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             ip6-localhost
```

I expect `cat /mnt/etc/hosts` to output the same, but in reality it output:

```
$ cat /mnt/etc/hosts
cat: /mnt/etc/hosts: No such file or directory
```

I created a stub file at `/system/etc/hosts` in my system root and tried again:

```
$ sudo mkdir /system
$ sudo mkdir /system/etc
$ echo "STUB" | sudo tee /system/etc/hosts
STUB
$ sudo mkdir /system/etc
$ cat /mnt/etc/hosts
STUB
```

As expected, it printed contents of `/system/etc/hosts` instead of `/mnt/system/etc/hosts`, as I wanted.

I want all symbolic links in the mounted folder `/mnt` to be resolved as if it was mounted at root `/`, so all symbolic links are resolved correctly.
Is there any way I can do that without actually changing anything in the mounted filesystem (redefining symbolic links to point to `/mnt{ACTUAL LINK}`)?

Comment: That's how symbolic links with absolute link targets work. It should be `etc -> system/etc` to work as you want. You could use a `chroot` environment.

Comment: I highly doubt that it's actually an ISO. It just doesn't make sense to use the ISO9660 filesystem for Android system image.

Comment: @gronostaj It's probably not. See [the previous question from this user](https://superuser.com/q/1778645/432690).

Comment: @Bodo, can I use chroot if there is no executable shell in the mounted folder? The image is android arm32 image, so it has only arm executables, so I get error `chroot: failed to run command ‘/system/bin/sh’: Exec format error` when I try to use chroot

Comment: @gronostaj, yeah, sorry, it's not an iso, just a android's .img image file

Comment: I don't know if there is a way to solve the shell problem with `chroot`, and you might get other problems because of missing/wrong binaries. An overlay file system would allow to replace files. I suggest to [edit] your question and explain what you want to achieve at the end.